# protractor get element link inside nested div

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

nested div structure and inside it i have link

like this:

```
<div>
  <div>
        <a ng-click>
```

Now i reached the second div successfully, but I wasn't able to reach the second div and to click it(need to test if the click works)

My structure:
[image]

How i select the selected element in the picture and click it? thanks
Can you help? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [CSS Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

```
var el = element(by.css('a[ng-click="openService()"]'));
// or using the $() shorthand
// var el = $('a[ng-click="openService()"]');
el.click();
```

If that doesn't work, you can try [cssContainingText()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText)

```
var el = element(by.cssContainingText('a', 'gfd'));
```

Or it's close relative [linkText](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.By.linkText).

```
var el = element(by.linkText('gfd'))
```